# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog inside PropertyChangeListener causes unexpected behavior

Tags: java, swing

I have created a checkable menu item with `JCheckBoxMenuItem`. What I tried to do is when the checkbox gets checked, a message should appear:

```
 JCheckBoxMenuItem checkbox = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Checkbox");
    checkbox.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> {
        boolean isCheck = ((JCheckBoxMenuItem) evt.getSource()).isSelected();
        if(isCheck){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You checked the checkbox", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
```

However when I tried to check the checkbox, nothing appears. The second time I click on the `JMenu` a bunch of modal appears, and causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:117)
at javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.clearSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:151)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI$MouseGrabber.cancelPopupMenu(BasicPopupMenuUI.java:917)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI$MouseGrabber.eventDispatched(BasicPopupMenuUI.java:828)
at java.awt.Toolkit$SelectiveAWTEventListener.eventDispatched(Toolkit.java:2425)
at java.awt.Toolkit$ToolkitEventMulticaster.eventDispatched(Toolkit.java:2317)
at java.awt.Toolkit.notifyAWTEventListeners(Toolkit.java:2275)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4777)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)  
...
```

What is causing that to happen?

Comment: `PropertyChangeListener` is not the appropriate listener to use in this case, an `ActionListener` would be better

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ah, thanks! It works now, but what are the differences between them?

Comment: `ActionListener` is a general listener used by the button API (in particular, but not exclusively) to provide notification of when the button is triggered, regardless of how it was triggered.  The `PropertyChangeListener` is "generally" used for support of the bean API, but it can be used for some other "general" notifications if you know what to listen for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is causing that to happen?

You're using the wrong listener for the wrong job.  `PropertyChangeListener` is not the appropriate listener for what you are trying to achieve, instead, you should be using an `ActionListener`...

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem checkbox = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Checkbox");
checkbox.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
        boolean isCheck = ((JCheckBoxMenuItem)e.getSource()).isSelected();
        if (isCheck) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You checked the checkbox", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
});
```

`PropertyChangeListener` doesn't actually (at least under my test) trigger any events when the selected state of the `JCheckBoxMenuItem` is changed, but your code did cause it continually throw up a dialog forcing me to kill the program

Have a look at [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html), [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that is the problem with `JOptioanPane` or with the listener. You can use `System.out.println("check="+check);` first instead of showing `JOptionPane`. If it was OK, then change the `Listener` type